# QFileDialog allows to select multiple dirs but don't return them

Tags: c++, qt

QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory allows to select multiple directories but after return the string is empty. How to make it to have those selected directories stored either in QString or QStringList (preferred).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the docs for `QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(.....)`, it doesn't state anywhere that it can return multiple directories.

> This is a convenience static function that will return an existing
>   directory selected by the user.

Comment: ok, thanks, it just weird that it allows to select multiple dirs at a time

Answer (score 1):

The dialog shouldn't allow multiple selection; it's a bug: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-21372

Unfortunately QFileDialog doesn't seem to support what you want to do (even if you create an instance of it rather than using the static method). I presume you're on Windows, as it's the native Windows dialog that supports (erroneously in this case) the multiple directory selection. If you don't care about running on other platforms, you could look at qfiledialog_win.cpp, specifically `qt_win_CID_get_existing_directory()`, and adapt that to your purposes.

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to help you, when we can't see your code.

Try to look here, if you are using it the right way: 
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_QDir_and_QFileDialog_in_Qt

Comment: That's not really true, this question does not need code for being answered.